# style not working for p tag in gradle

Tags: node.js, pug

Hi I am new to both `gradle` and `nodejs`. 
I am trying to add padding for p tag in jade. my jade file goes as below

```
extends layout

block content
  center
    h1= title
    p Rate-Review-Ride
  p(style='padding-left:500px;')
  | Gradle is a project automation tool that builds upon the concepts of Apache Ant and Apache Maven and introduces a Groovy-based domain-specific language
  | (DSL) instead of the more traditional XML form of declaring the project configuration.
  | Unlike Apache Maven, which defines lifecycles, and Apache Ant, where targets are invoked based upon a depends-on partial ordering, Gradle uses a directed acyclic graph ("DAG") to determine the order in which tasks can be run.
  | Gradle was designed for multi-project builds which can grow to be quite large, and supports incremental builds by intelligently determining which parts of the build tree are up-to-date, so that any task dependent upon those parts will not need to be re-executed.
  | The initial plugins are primarily focused around Java, Groovy and Scala development and deployment, but more languages and project workflows are on the roadmap.
  | dfs dfd fdsfdf dfljjf ofds fojdofjdosj fojdofjdofjdof
```

but its not adding padding to paragraph. Same style if I add for `center` in above code it adds padding. Please explain me how `style` works in `jade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jade like a python is very strict to line indentation. You need to put | two spaces to the right, like this:

```
block content
  center
    h1= title
    p Rate-Review-Ride
  p(style='padding-left:500px;') 
    | Gradle is a project automation tool that builds upon the concepts of Apache Ant and Apache Maven and introduces a Groovy-based domain-specific language
    | (DSL) instead of the more traditional XML form of declaring the project configuration.
    | Unlike Apache Maven, which defines lifecycles, and Apache Ant, where targets are invoked based upon a depends-on partial ordering, Gradle uses a directed acyclic graph ("DAG") to determine the order in which tasks can be run.
    | Gradle was designed for multi-project builds which can grow to be quite large, and supports incremental builds by intelligently determining which parts of the build tree are up-to-date, so that any task dependent upon those parts will not need to be re-executed.
    | The initial plugins are primarily focused around Java, Groovy and Scala development and deployment, but more languages and project workflows are on the roadmap.
    | dfs dfd fdsfdf dfljjf ofds fojdofjdosj fojdofjdofjdof
```

Without it text will not be in `<p>` tag.